# Переход по страницам?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Народ, как производится переход по страницам с шапкой, то есть шапка остается, а контент меняется. Можете подробно объяснить, как сделать это?

Пример то, что мог [найти](http://bsc.global/)

Comment: Народ, спрашивает, а ты сам чего сделал и чего именно не получается?

Answer (score 2):

переход по страницам можно сделать используя GET запрос, а также через Ajax подгрузку нужного контента в какой-либо блок на сайте

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере на каждой новой странице дублируется код с шапкой.

Для SPA используются более хитрые библиотеки, например React

Вот хороший пример
https://codepen.io/pzi/pen/xRJPey